# Facebook privacy policy error

Tags: facebook

In Facebook developer account I am creating an app Id for one of my android App's.
In Settings -> auth-dialog I copied the below URL in Privacy Policy.

http://developers.facebook.com/policy/

I got an error saying ...

Error
A valid Privacy Policy URL must be provided in order to be compliant with Facebook Platform Policy.

I gave the same URL for my other app few months back and it worked. Please suggest.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a question which should be asked of the Customer Service department for the company you are dealing with. Please see: [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746) and [Why we're not customer support for \[your favorite company\]](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255745/).

Answer (score -8, accepted):

The problem is that that field must be filled with a privacy policy that refers to your app, not to Facebook.

Comment: self-promotion - if you want to list your service thats fine but you should list alternatives especially since your site is a pay service

Comment: I fear there are no other services generating privacy policies for facebook apps. Moreover, the service comes with a free version already used by thousands of developers :)
Thank you anyway for the suggestion, I'll surely keep it for the future!

Comment: Tsss... it's not just promotion it's a paying service. Funny thing, it's built in Italy, the country of lazy lawyers.

Comment: Free privacy policy generator: http://www.generateprivacypolicy.com/ , http://www.freeprivacypolicy.com/

Answer (score 8):

If the URL you copied into that question is the one you're trying on your own app, that's completely invalid, it needs to be a real privacy policy for your app - you can't just link to facebook's developer policy, that has nothing to do with how you use the data you retrieve from users of your app

If not, and you're using a real privacy policy URL:

1. Check it's definitely a valid URL that [Facebook's Debug Tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) can reach
2. Try saving the basic settings - including privacy policy URL, then going back and changing the other settings you need

Comment: Its for my own android app.I tried to integrate facebook to my app. Fo r that I created an app ID. But as per facebook developer guidelines we have place the privacy policy link Privacy Policy textbox. I verified the URL using FB debug tool and it is valid.

Answer (score 4):

with the given URL http://developers.facebook.com/policy/ you are pointing to the facebook privacy policy, not the policy for your own App,
but for making your application live or public it is must that you should enter the valid url for your application's **PRIVACY POLICY** and **TERMS AND CONDITIONS POLICY**.
There are many tools available online for generating these policies for particular application by providing some of basic information, I would recommend you to use https://termsfeed.com/ for this particular work.
i also use it in my applications and i assure you that it will work fine.
This site will provide you a final URL for both policies, you just have to copy and paste it simple in the facebook developers app setting box and then all set.