# Facebook - This must be a valid privacy policy url

Tags: asp.net-mvc, facebook, facebook-apps

I have an **MVC** site that users Facebook to log-in users.
When trying to approve the Facebook app, the only field I can't get to be satisfied
 is the 
Privacy Policy URL field. I get the following error:

[image]

Can't  seem to figure out what's wrong. The page is public and can be accessed without authentication.

It contains non-english text (hebrew).

Does the page content needs to comply to some structure ?

Comment: What is the URL to the privacy policy? My guess is that you are not returning 200 OK

Comment: The URL is fine, I checked it many times. It returns 200 OK. I inspected it in fiddler in any possible way. it's ok.

Comment: It is not. We only check that you return 200 OK. If you give me the app id I can check it for you

Comment: @wizkid Ok...great, the app id is: 316203145214828.

Comment: Your privacy policy that you added to that app works. If you have problem adding some other privacy policy url you need to give me that one

Comment: @WizKid so how it is suddenly works ? (for any one else that encounters the same bug)

Comment: My guess would be that you changed something on your side. Or that the internet connection between Facebooks servers and your server had problem when you tried to save

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at this? [Facebook privacy policy error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11710989/facebook-privacy-policy-error)
You may have missed one of the requirements.

Comment: I've already looked at this question but it didn't helped a lot. What I need to know is if Facebook actually analyzing the page content, and see that something is missing, or it's just some other technical issue. If the page's content is being analyzed maybe it is the Hebrew letters that interfere the process ?

Answer (score 0):

As WizKid says, it's was probably a temporary issue. Suddenly it just works.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seemed to be just the fact that a previously fetched request for the same URL was not authorised by my server at that time. May be the same might have happened to you too.

Solution: Just fetch the URL of Privacy Policy again using [Facebook's URL Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug). That's the thing between you and your peace of mind.