# Facebook is requesting a working privacy policy URL, valid URL returning a 206

Tags: facebook, facebook-sdk-4.0

We have had the same privacy policy URL for our facebook app since ~2013. This morning, facebook sent over a "warning" email that our application didn't have a valid privacy policy URL. I searched everywhere and could not find a contact email for their dev team.

I found in another post, [Facebook privacy policy error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11710989/facebook-privacy-policy-error) to try and use Facebook's debug tool to validate the URL. When I add the URL and submit it, it shows "206" (partial content). The URL itself links back to a PDF file, but again, this was never a problem in the last 5 years or so, the URL hasn't changed (and the app hasn't been updated), but now there seems to be a problem. Can anyone help me figure out how to get this addressed? or how to get into contact with FB dev support, directly?

Comment: Can you make it an HTML page instead? Facebook got a lot stricter about privacy in the last year.

Comment: We should perhaps not assume that everyone surfing the net has the ability to access PDF content on their device in the first place. I second @jwebb’s recommendation that you try to supply the URL to an HTML document instead.

Comment: @ryaninbinary - only 4 years later, did you resolve this issue?